# Does string contain three comma-separated numbers?

Tags: java, string, parsing

How do I check whether a string fits this format:

```
<number>,<number>,<number>
```

e.g.

```
3.0, 87546,0.8273456
```

i.e. three comma-separated values that can be parsed as doubles. Sometimes the string will contain something else (e.g. `Text,More text,42` or `anything, really`) and in such a case I just need to ignore it and move on to parsing the next string.

Right now I just try to parse the string as if it fits the expected format, and catch any resulting exception. What is a smarter and less expensive way of doing this? Hopefully without throwing/catching exceptions?

```
        String[] parsedLine = line.trim().split(",");
        if (parsedLine.length == 3) {
            try {
                xCoordinate = Double.parseDouble(parsedLine[0]);
                yCoordinate = Double.parseDouble(parsedLine[1]);
                groundElevation = Double.parseDouble(parsedLine[2]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                //This line does not contain numbers exclusively. 
                //Assume it's a header/comment.
                //Do nothing.
            }
        } else {
            //This is not in the expected x,y,z format. 
            //Assume it's a header/comment.
            //Do nothing.
        }
```

Comment: Mind that you need to correctly process the following: `1, "text, 1.5", 2`.

Comment: im not a java programmer, but what about using `try{int[] parsedLine = line.trim().split(",");}catch{// Not numbers}`

Comment: @Dementic: indeed, you're not a Java programmer. int and String are two different types in Java, and you can't just pretend a String[] is an int[]. And a catch block needs an exception.

Comment: @JBNizet - i was guessing that if the result is not integers, then it will fail, and the catch block will process. about the exception, well, would you want me to write all he's code?

Comment: @Dementic Java does not work like that. Casting a `String` to `int` won't work.

Comment: @Dementic: Your guesses are wrong. Java doesn't work like that. To be valid Java code, your suggestion should become exactly what the OP has done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have right now is probably the most bullet-proof (and in my view the easiest to understand) implementation possible.

I wouldn't change it, unless I had specific evidence from the profiler that it's an overall bottleneck (either in terms of CPU usage, or the amount of garbage created).

Comment: As I asked JB Nizet: But shouldn't exceptions "be used only in exceptional conditions"? Here I use them as a matter of course.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: I personally have no such objections to the use of exceptions. Ask yourself this: *what are the exact, specific reasons for why using exceptions in this manner should be avoided?*

Answer (score 2):

[Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html) are your friend; here's an example of how to [implement a pattern in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Answer (score 2):

There is no cleaner way. Your code is fine.

You ask: "But shouldn't exceptions "be used only in exceptional conditions"? Here I use them as a matter of course."

Well, Java doesn't have any `Double.isValid(String)` method. If it had, You could use it, but it doesn't. And even then, you would have to parse the double twice: once to check if it's a double, and once to get the double value.

What you have is a common idiom, and I doubt regular expressions will be more readable and faster than what you have.

Comment: But shouldn't exceptions "be used only in exceptional conditions"? Here I use them as a matter of course.

Comment: Except Java doesn't have any Double.isValid(String) method. If it had, You could use it, but it doesn't. And even then, you would have to parse the double twice: once to check if it's a double, and once to get the double value. What you have is a common idiom, and I doubt regexps will be more readable and faster than what you have.

Comment: Not sure that I'd agree with this answer.  Exceptions are supposed to be for "error" cases, and things that don't happen in the normal run of the processing.  I think it's cleaner to check the input against some kind of regular expression before doing the processing - the hard part is to work out exactly what should be in that regular expression.  This would be an excellent exercise for the original poster to try.

Comment: As I said, if following this rule blindly leads to code that is leass readable, less robust, and slower, I don't really see the point of following the rule.

Comment: I totally agree with JB Nizet on this one. However, if we assume number will be either integers, or real numbers in the form I.F (integer part and fraction part), then regexp is satisfactory.

Answer (score 2):

I think is not that expensive. `String.split()` will create a `Pattern` from your parameter and will split the String around that.

If you're worrying about the cost of the exceptions, then you could create a more complex pattern to match your string and you probably won't have them:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?),(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?),(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)$");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
if (matcher.matches()) {
   xCoordinate = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(1));
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions would be the natural solution to this. I and many others would immediately use that approach. However, you mention in your question that you are looking for a less expensive solution. Regular expressions would likely be more expensive in terms of resources used.

In response to your comments "shouldn't exception only be used in exceptional conditions", I would say that this problem *is* an exceptional condition; A problem where using exceptions in this way creates a more elegant solution.

Your current solution is simple, concise, and easy to understand (hence, easy to maintain). If it works, I wouldn't waste time changing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex for doubles from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29):

```
public boolean matches(String str) {
    final String Digits     = "(\\p{Digit}+)";
    final String HexDigits  = "(\\p{XDigit}+)";
    final String Exp        = "[eE][+-]?"+Digits;
    final String fpRegex    =
            ("[\\x00-\\x20]*"+  // Optional leading "whitespace"
                    "[+-]?(" + // Optional sign character
                    "NaN|" +           // "NaN" string
                    "Infinity|" +      // "Infinity" string

                    // A decimal floating-point string representing a finite positive
                    // number without a leading sign has at most five basic pieces:
                    // Digits . Digits ExponentPart FloatTypeSuffix
                    //
                    // Since this method allows integer-only strings as input
                    // in addition to strings of floating-point literals, the
                    // two sub-patterns below are simplifications of the grammar
                    // productions from the Java Language Specification, 2nd
                    // edition, section 3.10.2.

                    // Digits ._opt Digits_opt ExponentPart_opt FloatTypeSuffix_opt
                    "((("+Digits+"(\\.)?("+Digits+"?)("+Exp+")?)|"+

                    // . Digits ExponentPart_opt FloatTypeSuffix_opt
                    "(\\.("+Digits+")("+Exp+")?)|"+

                    // Hexadecimal strings
                    "((" +
                    // 0[xX] HexDigits ._opt BinaryExponent FloatTypeSuffix_opt
                    "(0[xX]" + HexDigits + "(\\.)?)|" +

                    // 0[xX] HexDigits_opt . HexDigits BinaryExponent FloatTypeSuffix_opt
                    "(0[xX]" + HexDigits + "?(\\.)" + HexDigits + ")" +

                    ")[pP][+-]?" + Digits + "))" +
                    "[fFdD]?))" +
                    "[\\x00-\\x20]*");// Optional trailing "whitespace"

    String pattern=fpRegex + "," + fpRegex + "," + fpRegex;
    return str.matches(pattern);
}
```

Comment: Maybe the options for hexadecimal, exponents, and the trailing fFdD are not required here.  I would go with something like KARASZI Istvan's answer, plus whitespace before and after each bracketed chunk.  This has the added benefit that you can iterate through the `matcher` to actually get the numbers out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex \d for digits. so something like this

\d+,\d+,\d+

sorry untested :)

Comment: That particular pattern will match the string ",," and "1,2,3" when decimal numbers are required.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex on whole text
This assumes there will be no space between the numbers and the commas, you can make relevant changes to add optional space chars

```
[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?,[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?,[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?
```

I just made the changes

```
[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?\s*,\s*[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?\s*,\s*[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?
```

This will be space friendly
Of-course you will have to test it though

Answer (score 0):

A good start would be to use the Pattern class: `boolean b = Pattern.matches(".*,.*,.*", str);`
However, to ensure you have numbers there you have to have a more complex regexp:

```
    String str = "3.0,87546,0.8273456";
    boolean b = Pattern.matches("^(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?),(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?),(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)$", str);
    if (b) {
        System.out.println("matches");
    } else {
        System.out.println("does not match");
    }

    // output: matches
```

EDIT: I see KARASZI already beat me up in speed, but still, the code is here...